# What can I do if I want to help localize the Ubuntu official website for Hong Kong people?

Tags: community, translation, chinese, localization

I see that there is a [simplified chinese version of the ubuntu **official website**](http://cn.ubuntu.com/) for people in mainland China but no traditional Chinese version for people in Hong Kong (or Taiwan). If I want to help localize the **official website** to make Ubuntu more popular in Hong Kong, what can I do?

Comment: Can you please post the URL of the site you are referring to?

Comment: This is the simplified chinese version: http://cn.ubuntu.com/

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think that's the result of regular translations by the Ubuntu community. My belief is that Canonical has special cased simplified Chinese by providing that version of the site. AFAIK there are no localized versions of the official site in other languages; see [this bug comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/website-localization/+bug/694338/comments/1), for instance.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson that looks like the right answer in this case, since It looks like there are no strings to translate on those pages either

Comment: @Mateo: Yeah.. I posted it as an answer as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think [cn.ubuntu.com](http://cn.ubuntu.com/) is the result of regular translations by the Ubuntu community. My belief is that Canonical has specialcased simplified Chinese by providing that version of the site. AFAIK there are no localized versions of the official site in other languages; see [this bug comment‌](https://bugs.launchpad.net/website-localization/+bug/694338/comments/1)​, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the [website localization Launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/website-localization) but I don't see a page for your language here yet.

So you should find some other folks interested in doing it :)

There are some more ideas and links on the [Contribute page](http://community.ubuntu.com/contribute/) of the website:

Links:

[Launchpad translations area](https://launchpad.net/+tour/translation)

[Ubuntu-Translators mailing list](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-translators)

[Ubuntu documentation team](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DocumentationTeam)

[Translations help](https://help.launchpad.net/Translations/StartingToTranslate) and [Translation guide](https://help.launchpad.net/Translations/Guide) and [how to join or create a translation team](https://help.launchpad.net/Translations/JoiningATranslationGroup?action=show&redirect=Translations%2FGroups)

Definitely get in touch with your local team:

[Ubuntu Hong Kong Team](http://loco.ubuntu.com/teams/ubuntu-hk/) and [Hong Kong translation team](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-l10n-zh-hk)

Comment: Is there a website like **[Transifex](http://www.transifex.com)** for me to help the translation directly?

Comment: @CasperLI I added some more links... seems like there isn't a page for your language yet in the website localization page (maybe I missed it?) so you may have to lead the charge yourself! But get in touch with the local team, and you will find out what is going on :)

Comment: I found [this one](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-l10n-zh-hk) but I don't see any page for translating the official website.

Comment: If it doesn't exist yet, I think you should get some people together to create it. 'Contact the admins' :)

Comment: the language codes should already exist - just type them in the address - https://translations.launchpad.net/website-localization/trunk/+pots/ubuntu-website-resources/zh/+translate - https://translations.launchpad.net/website-localization/trunk/+pots/ubuntu-website-resources/zh_TW/+translate - https://translations.launchpad.net/website-localization/trunk/+pots/ubuntu-website-resources/zh_HK/+translate

Comment: @CasperLI: If you want to help translating other things into zh_HK, that's the people to get in touch with. You may want to apply to join the team. (Please note that there are separate teams for [zh_HK](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-l10n-zh-hk) and [zh_TW](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-l10n-zh-tw).)